# 64-Megapixel Autofocus Camera for Raspberry Pi continue-autofocus

Tags: camera

Hi I get this camera Excellent quality camera, But can not stop the photo and get the image as a file
https://www.arducam.com/downloads/arducam_64mp_pi_camera_manual.pdf

Comment: Have you tried asking Arducam support / forum? It's their hardware and IIRC you're also have to use their kernel / firmware.

Comment: thank you Dirk, I send them this q and I continued to search in more forums, I managed to stop the resolution of the camera and then get another message and think I found in another forum interesting material today I will check it hope to succeed thank you very much
https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps/issues/144